# How to build react-native app for iOS properly?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I developed a react native app (version 57.4) on windows for android and it works fine.

Now I'm trying to build for iOS with no luck (as I don't have any experience with Xcode).

What I tried so far:

I knew that it requires a Mac and Xcode so I downloaded a VM, install Xcode.

- Git clone myApp
- react-native run-ios

But I got a lot of errors and build failures so after some search, I make these more steps:

- react-native link
- link some fonts manually
- add a pod file and pod install
- make some Xcode changes which I can't remember
- react-native run-ios
  And it works :)

BUT I had an issue with axios so I tried to fix it but I ruined the app so I removed the folder and re-cloned it again.

This time, I can't build successfully again!! and if it builds it crashes instantly!

My Question is what the exact steps do I need to make to build successfully on Mac (especially steps for Xcode)? including how to link all native dependencies correctly? and Is the pod file is necessary?

Comment: You did a risk in fact, you have to check the iOS each time you install a component or package. If I were in your shoes, I started with the components that installed. Check if they have any configuration in iOS and do them step by step. Some components needed to link manually in Xcode.

Comment: Yea I know that it's a risk. But actually, it worked! ... Now I can't get it to work again. I'm so confused :S

Comment: What kind of error you see now?

Comment: @MohamedGamal brother you should do some VCS and keep changes saved in commits!  while doing such critical things!

Comment: please add your package.json dependencies so i could tell what manual steps you need to do for successful linking!

Comment: in XCode make sure you have 3 things in check 

1: a developer account for apple associated with the project alongside provisioning profiles with that PackageName of your app! 

2: run basic react-native link  and try

if no luck then show the Package.json so we here could help

Comment: @Reza now it build successfully but it crashes instantly when opened in a simulator.

Comment: The only way to understand it is to go to your Xcode console(It is a box in the right bottom of Xcode) and see what is the error. It will say that which component causes the error.

Comment: @Rizwanatta my package.json is quite large .. I ask for the default steps for any native dependency which require linking ... Isn't there some files I should check as android >> which are: build.gradle, AndroidManifest.xml and MainApplication.java.

Comment: you want to check it for android? or ios?

Comment: For iOS. I just give an example of android linking process.